# Wordpress plugin with request approval form and approval check on the user page

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, user-management

I’m finding a feature on Wordpress and I don’t know if there are any plugin that can cover my needs.

I want to make a request form (especifically about scholarships request) only for registered users, so when the user log in can send the form. When the form was submitted, the admin can approval or reject the scholarship, and the user can know if the form has been approved or rejected via user panel (with an option of approved or rejected in a zone of the user panel).

Can I do that? Any plugin that can do it?

Edit: I saw these plugins but I think that can't do that:

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-registration-form-builder-with-submission-manager/

https://gravityflow.io/

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think any plugin give this type of functionality you have to use customization any plugin

Answer (score 0):

This plugins only approve or reject the user profile.
I will guide how to implement this.

you create the scholarship custom post type. The user can log in and fill-up the form and form data place on scholarship post type. you will set the post to publish status set as "Draft". Admin can check this posts and admin can post publish.

Thank you.

Comment: And how the user can check if the "form" has been approved or not? How to implement on his user panel.

Comment: You will set a relation between user and post. If the post is created then the post id put in user meta and this using this post id you will add one column on the user panel. 

If an admin can approve this form using user email you will send the email on publishing the post publish hook.

Than you.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry.

Comment: User fill-up the form after login and submit this form then create the post. set post author id to login user id or set post meta using post id.
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'user_id', $user_id);

Comment: If an admin can publish the post then you will run hook.
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $author = $post->post_author;
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $subject = 'publish post';
    $message = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article "%s" has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
    $message .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
    $headers[] = '';
    wp_mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );

Comment: But I need to have a custom field of upload file on the form too.

Comment: https://unitedwebsoft.in/blog/wordpress-custom-post-type-add-form-in-frontend-for-users/ can you please the following this link?